# [Hardhat]: Passing ether to function during call cause an error to be triggered

Tags: hardhat, testing

I have this test suite written with Hardhat

```typescript
      it('Should reveal bid', async () => {
        const { blindAuction, bidder3, bidData } = await loadFixture(
          deployBlindAuctionFixture
        );

        const values = bidData['bidder3'].values.map(parseEther);
        const secrets = bidData['bidder3'].secrets.map(encodeBytes32String);

        bidData['bidder3'].values.forEach(async (value, index) => {
          const hashedBid = solidityPackedKeccak256(
            ['uint', 'bytes32'],
            [
              parseEther(value),
              encodeBytes32String(bidData.bidder3.secrets[index]),
            ]
          );

          const deposit = generateRandomDeposit();

          await expect(blindAuction.connect(bidder3).bid(hashedBid))
            .to.emit(blindAuction, 'SuccessfulBid')
            .withArgs(bidder3.address);
        });

        const TIME = 60 * 60 * 2;

        time.increase(TIME);

        console.log(
          'bids',
          await blindAuction.connect(bidder3).getBidsByBidder(bidder3.address)
        );

        await blindAuction.connect(bidder3).revealBids(values, secrets);
      });
```

and here is how the solidity functions are defined.

```
    function getBidsByBidder(
        address bidder
    ) external view returns (Bid[] memory) {
        return bids[bidder];
    }

    function bid(
        bytes32 _hashedBid
    ) external payable biddingIsActive(block.timestamp) {
        console.log("Deposit is %o", msg.value);
        bids[msg.sender].push(Bid({blindBid: _hashedBid, deposit: msg.value}));
        emit SuccessfulBid(msg.sender);
    }

    function revealBids(
        uint[] calldata _values,
        bytes32[] calldata _secrets
    ) external biddingHasEnded(block.timestamp) {
        uint lengthOfBids = bids[msg.sender].length;

        console.log("Length of bids is %o", lengthOfBids);

        if (_values.length != lengthOfBids && _secrets.length != lengthOfBids) {
            revert InCompleteBidData(msg.sender);
        }

        uint totalRefund = 0;

        for (uint i = 0; i < bids[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            (uint value, bytes32 secret) = (_values[i], _secrets[i]);

            Bid storage currentBid = bids[msg.sender][i];

            console.log("Bid Deposit is %o", currentBid.deposit);

            if (
                currentBid.blindBid ==
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(value, secret))
            ) {
                if (value <= highestBid || msg.sender == highestBidder) {
                    totalRefund += currentBid.deposit;
                } else if (value > highestBid) {
                    if (highestBidder != address(0)) {
                        refunds[highestBidder] += highestBid;
                    }

                    highestBid = value;
                    highestBidder = msg.sender;

                    emit HighestBidIncreased(msg.sender);
                } else {
                    refunds[msg.sender] += currentBid.deposit;
                }
            }

            currentBid.blindBid = bytes32(0);
        }

        if (msg.sender != highestBidder) {
            refunds[msg.sender] = totalRefund;
        }

        console.log("Total Refund is %o ", totalRefund);
    }
```

These are the issues I am currently facing:

1. For some reason, when I pass a value with the bid function, I get an error that I am passing incomplete bid data but when I don't pass a value, the function runs correctly.
2. When I run the function to get the bids by a bidder inside the loop, I get a response but when I run it outside the loop, it doesn't work. I am not quite sure why this happens and yes, my mapping is defined as public.
3. Is there a better way, I could have written my loop better?

I would appreciate any help towards this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const options = {
    value: ethers.parseEther("0.001"),
};

await expect(blindAuction.connect(bidder3).bid(hashedBid), options)
    .to.emit(blindAuction, "SuccessfulBid")
    .withArgs(bidder3.address);
```

> The **options.value** property is equivalent to the **msg.valu**e that will be captured in the function qualified by payable.

---

#### See also

- https://vsupalov.com/ethers-call-payable-solidity-function/

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it still throws the same error.